# Assign global variable inside jquery submit function and pass to regex function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tabletop.js

Assign value to global tracking variable on submit of form.

```
var tracking;

$('.form-inline').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tracking = jQuery('input[name="tracking"]').val();
  init()
})
```

execute function init()

```
function init() {
  Tabletop.init({
    key: public_spreadsheet_url,
    callback: showInfo,
    simpleSheet: true
  })
}
```

Which initiates the showInfo callback

```
var zipMatches = "";
function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
  alert('Callback initiated..');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var myRegex = '/' + tracking + '/';
    console.log(myRegex)
    if (myRegex.test(data[i].tracking)) {
      zipMatches = zipMatches + data[i].location_1 + ", " + data[i].location_2 + ", " + data[i].location_3;
    }
  }
  //write it into the DOM 
  var myElement = document.querySelector(".myJSON");
  myElement.innerHTML = "<h3>List of Zipcodes that match tracking ID: </h3><p>" + zipMatches + "</p>";
}
```

> myRegex.test is not a function

However regex function works with hardcoded value

```
if (/ABCD123/.test(data[i].tracking)) {...
```

How do I pass the regex value as a global variable?

..

Edit (working callback function):

```
function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
  var regexp = new RegExp(tracking);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (regexp.test(data[i].tracking)) {
      zipMatches = zipMatches + data[i].location_1 + ", " + data[i].location_2 + ", " + data[i].location_3;
    }
  }..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plese try with following sol:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(tracking);
```

and please put it outside of forloop. So it is optimized.

Since you have tried 
  `var regexp = "/" + tracking + "/";` will convert it into string. Not regex object. So you won't get test method in it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This was indeed a string and not an object.  Definitively a rookie mistake.  Thank you for the additional info on where to place this information.   I have added corrected code above.